# Let iPhone audio play while AVPlayer plays video in my application?

Tags: ios, avplayer

In my application I am playing a video like so:

```
    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("myVideo", withExtension: "mp4")
    let videoPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: url)
    videoPlayer.play()
```

When the video plays any other audio from other applications stops.

For example, I am listening to iTunes Radio and that stops playing when this code is run.

How can I allow this video to play without interfering with other audio sources on the phone?

I want to be able to play the video an also listen to iTunes Radio. Main reason is because my video in my app has no volume....

Thanks

Comment: Do you know what an AVAudioSession is?

Comment: Ok, so I should use an AVAudioSession to configure the settings I want?

Comment: Right, you should _always_ have an AVAudioSession if your app makes sounds. It governs how those sounds relate to the sounds of other apps. Look into the different categories.

Comment: See also the discussion in my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch27.html#_audio_session